# Changing char[] in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, replace

I looking for a answer and can't find nowhere. I hope you'll help me. I write a simple app which include struct with a name of worker and . But when i want to change value of name i can't do it. I don't know why. Maybe you can't help me or you know another ways to do it? My code:

```
struct workers {
char name[256]="no";
int pay=-1;
};

void addOne(struct workers work[20]) {
    char name[256];
    int i=0;
    for (i = 0; work[i].name != "no"; i++) {}
    printf_s("Enter name of worker: ");
    scanf_s("%s", &name);
    //-----error here-----
    work[i].name = name;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    struct workers work[20];
    for (i = 0;i < 20; i++) {
        if (work[i].name != "no") {
            work[i].pay = 100 * i;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf_s("%s\t%d\n", work[i].name, work[i].pay);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not valid C code. You can't initialize struct members in the definition of the struct.

Comment: But i don't init them in definition. I just definite default name and salary. And in function addOne i just want to change their value

Comment: "*I just definite default name and salary.*" Yes, that's a syntax error. You can't do that in C.

Comment: OK, but how can i add members?

Answer (score -1):

```
work[i].name = name;
```

The above line is where the problem is.

Change as below:

```
snprintf( work[i].name, sizeof(work[i].name), "%s", name);
```

What you have done is trying to change the base pointer of the array and not the name.

Also there were few more errors in the code, pls resolve them.

It is not possible to set default values to structure as you have done in C.

You have to write code to init each array instance name variable with "no" in a loop and then use one of the string comparison functions to compare the strings. And then call your addOne.

Comment: `strncpy ( work[i].name, name, strlen(name));` is a **very bad** advice.

Comment: Never use `strncpy`, basically.

Comment: ya, understood the issue on using strncpy.... the alternative i see is snprintf to be used as below `snprintf( work[i].name, sizeof(work[i].name), "%s", name);`